# Options to circumvent the limitation of 20 relationship group members per relationship group

Tags: relationships, npsp

We would like to build a household / relationship group with more than 20 relationship group members.  currently there is a limit on the number of group members.  Also is it possible to add one group to another group as a group member.'

More on the feature:  http://login.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_relgroups_getstart.pdf

Comment: Are you referring to the limit of custom relationship fields per object or something else?

Comment: This is the feature i am talking about:  http://login.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_relgroups_getstart.pdf

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the standard group object, then the answer is yes:

[image]